# "The President Obama" or "President Obama"?

Tags: articles

I wonder which of these is right, or are the both expressions right? What do you think?

Comment: Generally the second, without the article.  I cannot think of any context in which the first would be acceptable.

Comment: Is that true for all the other presidents? I mean President XXX, right? And can that "president" exchanged with all the other job positions such as Chef, Accountant etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [President vs. The President](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203703/president-vs-the-president)

Comment: What does your research show, Reactor4?  Please provide it in your question.

Comment: President is a title here, not the name of a job.  If Jane Doe is an accountant, nobody calls her Accountant Doe.  But yes, this applies to all people who are accorded the title of "President."  Why would you think it would apply only to one man?

Comment: Cause I've seen the expression of "the Chef XXX" all over the internet and sometimes I see they are talking about "the" president XXX too. I thought maybe it applies to the US dialect.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?  Perhaps you are misinterpreting.  The word "chief" can also be used as an adjective.

Comment: Suppose there was also a famous painter called Obama. If I told you I was a big fan of Obama you might reasonably ask me: _The painter Obama or the president Obama?_ But here I'm using president as an occupation, not a title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is Greek president vs Who is THE Greek President](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71760/who-is-greek-president-vs-who-is-the-greek-president)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *President* is being used as a title, there's no definite article:

> President Obama gave a speech today.

If *president* is the subject of the sentence and *Obama* is being used as an appositive, then you would use a definite article:

> The president, Obama, gave a speech today.

However, the former is much more common than the latter, because unless you're talking to someone who has no idea that the U.S. president is named Obama, there's no need for an appositive that specifies who the president is.

Comment: Do you mean an apposition?

Comment: An appositive is a word or phrase in apposition: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/appositive